# C++ redefine a variable on purpose

Tags: c++

I was wondering if the redefinition of a variable in C++ is possible, for example:

```
void some_function(int some_argument) {
    float some_argument=(float) some_argument;
    // Do stuff
    return some_argument;
}
```

Is there some way to do this? I know you can change the name, but it's so much cleaner if the name is the same. If not, is there some reason this feature wasn't included?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can, it's called shadowing, but you can't use the old definition in the initialiser. (It'll use the new one.)

Comment: What do you mean so much cleaner? Just give it a new name and ignore the function parameter.

Comment: Why not just use the argument, if you want to store it in temporary then make one, how would you refer to original one if you did this?

Comment: @pmdj You can, but you need to be in a new scope.  What the OP wants is not supported by the language.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Even with a new scope, you need intermediate variable to initialize the new var with the old one.

Comment: You may want to read up on static typing? (Or maybe strong typing; I always get them confused.)

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah.  I was just talking about the shadowing.  You have to have a new scope to shadow.  You cannot shadow a parameter otherwise as it has function scope.

Comment: Postfix a `_` if you want to keep the name's semantics: `void some_function(int some_argument_)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some way to do this?

You can create a new scope and define a new variable of the same name which shadows the name of the function argument.

```
void some_function(int some_argument) {
   {
      float some_argument = 0;
      // Do stuff
   }
}
```

However, you cannot use:

```
void some_function(int some_argument) {
   {
      float some_argument = (float)some_argument;
      // Do stuff
   }
}
```

In the second case, the initialization does not use the function argument to initialize the shadowing variable. It is as bad as

```
int i = i;
```

Avoid all these hassles by:

1. Using different names for the variable and the argument.

   ```
   void some_function(int some_argument_in) {
      float some_argument = (float)some_argument_in;
      // Do stuff
   }
   ```
2. Using a function overload.

   ```
   void some_function(float some_argument) {
      // Do stuff
   }

   void some_function(int some_argument) {
      some_function((float)some_argument);
   }
   ```

Comment: Good answer. Is there some reason variable shadowing can't use previous values? Is there a reason shadowing can't be done in the same scope? I liked the overloading, it's the cleanest so far. If I was calling the function often, would the overloading affect performance? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following gives warnings about possible loss of data when converting between `int` and `float` but it demonstrates how you can pass the variable as one type and work with it in the function as another:

```
float some_function(int some_argument) {
    // Do stuff
    return some_argument;
}

int main()
{
    float oldval = 3;
    float newval = some_function(oldval);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is ok when the new type can be implicitly casted, which is not my case. Sorry I didn't cover that in the question.

Comment: You could add a [user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) to keep the code clean for this and other functions.

Comment: Oh, that's a nice way too, but it kind of pollutes the outside environment of the function.